# How can I determine what commits cause a conflict?

Tags: git, git-merge

I'm doing `git merge develop feature/ticket-123`, and I'm getting merge conflicts. The conflicts are complex enough that I want to see the context of the changes being made, so that I can resolve them properly.

I can see which files have merge conflicts, but those files only say what is from `develop` and what is from `feature/ticket-123`. How can I see the specific commits that cause the conflict, so I can resolve the conflict better?

I had a look at [How to resolve merge conflicts in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/fix-merge-conflicts-in-git) , but I couldn't see anything that had this information

Comment: I am not entirely sure but when running `git status` it does show if merge can be fast-forwarded or not (It shows only for tracking branch)

Comment: I would use [git blame](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame)

Answer (score 0):

Until somebody comes up with a better answer, here's a workaround: Do a `git rebase develop` on the feature branch instead of merging, to apply the commits one by one and solve conflicts immediately.